# ¿Cómo llenar una tabla anidada HTML con datos desde JSON?

Tags: html, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una tabla HTML la cual lleno con JSON desde el controlador.

La tabla está anidada a otra. Mediante las funciones datos y datos2, obtengo los datos de las tablas.

He logrado llenar la tabla anidada por medio del id de la primera tabla pasándolo como parámetro al controller de la función que llena la segunda tabla, pero solo llena los primeros datos. Es decir la columna Zona tiene un id el cual esta relacionado con la columna Ingeniero de la tabla anidada.

Aquí dejo los datos, espero darme a entender.

Código:

```html
<div class="table-responsive table-condensed table-sm table-bordered tabla">
  <table class="table table-hover content-tabla" id="Datos" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-success">
        <td>Código</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Pronosticado</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Pronosticado Acumulado</td>
        <td>Entregado</td>
        <td>Diferencia</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Pronosticado Actual</td>
        <td>Entregado</td>
        <td>Diferencia</td>
        <td>Activar</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```html
    <script src="~/js/Jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var id;
        
   $(document).ready(function () {
        datos();
    });


function datos() {
  $.getJSON(siteURL + "MyController/MyAction", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {
      $('#Datos').append('<tr>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<img alt = "" style = "cursor: pointer;" src = "' + siteURL + 'Image/icon_plus.png" />' +
        '<div style="display:none">' +
        '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Tabla2">' +
        '<thead>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th>Ingeniero</th>' +
        '<th>Pronostico Total</th>' +
        '<th></th>' +
        '<th>Pronostico Acumulado</th>' +
        '<th>Entregado</th>' +
        '<th>Diferencia</th>' +
        '<th></th>' +
        '<th>Pronostico Semana Actual</th>' +
        '<th>Entregado</th>' +
        '<th>Diferencia</th>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '<tbody>' +

        '</tbody>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.Zona + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.Pronostico + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + '' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.PronosticoAA + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.Entregado + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.DiferenciaAA + '%' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + '' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.PronosticoSA + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.EntregadoSA + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.DiferenciaSA + '%' + '</td>' +
        '</tr>');
        datos2(opt.id);
    });
  }, 'json');
}

function datos2(id) {
  $.getJSON(siteURL + "MyController2/MyAction2=id="+id, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {
      $('#Tabla2').append('<tr>' +
        '<td>' + opt.Ingeniero + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.Pronostico + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + '' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.PronosticoAA + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.Entregado + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.DiferenciaAA + '%' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + '' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.PronosticoSA + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.EntregadoSA + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + opt.DiferenciaSA + '%' + '</td>' +
        '</tr>');
    });
  }, 'json');
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controller:

```
//tabla 1
public JsonResult MyAction()
{
    List<ClassC> res = bd.Database.SqlQuery<ClassC>("SELECT...").ToList();
    return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

//tabla2
public JsonResult MyAction2(int id)
{
  List<ClassC> res2 = bd.Database.SqlQuery<ClassC>(
    "select.... where V.IdForaneo in (" + id + ") "
  ).ToList();

  return Json(res2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JSON de la tabla1 (el campo IdRegion es la columna Zona):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

JSON de la tabla 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De donde sale #tabla1? no encuentro ningun elemento con ese id. Lo mismo con #dataTableCurvaxIng

Comment: Hola error de copy paste, ya lo corregi @Mani

Comment: Recien te escribi una solucion por aca pero estoy seguro que la escribi mal y no te va a funcionar. De todas maneras estoy casi seguro que lo que tenes que hacer va por ahi. El elemento #tabla2 no se crea hasta que no está creada la tabla1, entonces el javascript que la carga tiene que ejecutarse una vez que el documento ya este listo. No me doy cuenta ahora como lo solucionarias exactamente pero estoy casi seguro que es por eso. Esperemos que lo lea alguno con mas experiencia

Comment: ``$(document).find('#tabla2').append("Aca va todo el append");`` fijate si esa linea te ayuda (reemplazala por ``$('#Tabla2').append``

Comment: Osea cambien el nombre del id? la t por T ? @Mani

Comment: no, me confundi con la mayuscula, el reemplazo es ``$('#Tabla2').`` por ``$(document).find('#Tabla2').``; de todas maneras no estoy seguro si andará

Comment: @Mani hola, no funcionó :c

Comment: Perdon que te use para hacer pruebas, ja... otras alternativas pueden ser ``$(document).ready('#Tabla2').`` o ``$(window).on( "load", function(){$(#Tabla2).append(...)})``

Comment: Gracias por su aporte, pero no funciona @Mani

Comment: Amigo disculpa, no entendí mucho el resultado esperado, dado que para llenar una tabla dentro de otra en vez de colocar la ejecución de la function en la misma altura, la funcion `datos2()` debe invocarse dentro de `datos()` así tendrás la ejecución de la tabla 2 en el escalado correcto. Sin embargo, si pudieses dibujar un resultado esperado con gusto te ayudaré con el código de respuesta de no ser el entregado.

Comment: @harifo hola añadi una imagen con el resultado que espero obtener, comprendo que debo invocar la funcion datos2() dentro de datos() pero nose como porque añadiendo simplemente "datos2();" no hace nada

Comment: Podrías adjuntar los Json que retornan?
Ademas podrías indicar como se realcionan las tablas mencionadas?

Comment: @LuisFernando he actualizado mi pregunta, espero ser mas claro, gracias

Comment: Me refería al json como tal, no al controller. Es para tratar de simular correctamente el ejemplo. Si tu json tiene data que no quieres que veamos puedes poner data de prueba. El json mas que todo es por la estrutura. Ademas veo en el JS #tabla2 y en el HTML no lo veo. Puedes aclarar esa parte?

Comment: @Huntzberger los datos de ingenieros que aparecen en el resultados todos son de la primera zona en este caso "Los Reyes" ?

Comment: si esos son correctos @Juanmhs

Comment: Porque pienso que el error pudiera ser lo siguiente por cada `<tr>`de la tabla `Datos` que serian las zonas estas creando un tabla con el id `Tabla2` osea es una tabla con el id repetido, si en la función `datos()` el id de la `Tabla2` le concatenas el `opt.id` que le pasas a la funcion `datos2()` y dentro de la función acomodas el id de la `'Tabla2'+opt.id` así obtendrías un identificador único para cada tabla anidada del `<tr>` y al ajax de la función `datos2()` llenaría la tabla especifica, no se si me explique bien puedo ponerla en la solución para explicar mejor si no funciona eliminarla

Comment: @LuisFernando tabla2 se crea en la funcion datos(), donde se llena la tabla1 ya agregue el JSON

Comment: El JSON deberías pegarlo como texto en vez de poner una imagen. Recomendablemente pocas filas así no se alarga mucho la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error podría ser el siguiente por cada `<tr>` creado en la función `datos()` se genera una tabla anidada con el id `Tabla2` con lo cual estamos repitiendo la tabla con el mismo id, por ende cuando se ejecuta la función `datos2()` la primera vez encuentra una sola tabla anidada con el id `Tabla2` y anexa los `<tr>`, la segunda vez que se ejecuta encuentra dos tablas con el id `Tabla2` y anexa los `<tr>` a la primera coincidencia

**Solución**

Se debería crear un identificador único por cada tabla anidada seria cambiar la siguiente linea de la función `datos()`:

```js
'<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Tabla2">' +
```

Por

```js
'<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Tabla2-'+opt.IdRegion+'">' +
```

Seguidamente cambiar la siguiente linea de la función `datos2()`

```js
$('#Tabla2').append('<tr>' +
```

Por

```js
$('#Tabla2-'+opt.IdRegion).append('<tr>' +
```

Comment: Hola gracias por el aporte, ya lo intente pero ahora ya no muestra ningun dato de la tabla2

Comment: En vez de id inténtalo con ‘idRegion’

Comment: si, puse IdRegion

Comment: Voy a modificarlo en la respuesta para que veas cómo es

Comment: Ya lo modifique en la respuesta a ver si te funciona

Comment: Hola ya lo probé y funcionó muchas gracias